# Can Postgres resolve character escapes passed down from RESP API to JSONB?

Tags: python, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a Python API that inserts data into Postgres table using stored procedure that takes in a jsonb and does an insert into table. example:

```
create function insert_new_employee(i jsonb) returns json as:
    $$
    begin
        insert into newhire(name, payload) values (i ->> 'name', i)
    end
    $$
```

When I do a test insert using SQL client such as datagrip as such it inserts successfully:

```
select insert_new_employee('{"name":"alfred"}')
```

However, when I use Python API the payload gets transformed into:

```
"{\"name\":\"alfred\"}"
```

Because of the escaping the name doesn't get parsed and stored into the name column however the jsonb payload column takes it in.

Is there a way for Postgres to clean up and deal with character escape when request are passed through API?

Comment: You might want to check if the python API supports taking JSON objects directly instead of JSON strings.

Comment: you mention that the jsonb payload column takes it in. can you provide the table schema where the payload is stored? it would be possible to trigger an insert into `newhire` from the json payload without having to fix mangled text first.

Comment: I am using SQLAlchemy and when I changed it from JSON String to Object like @vrtx54234 mentioned and it worked. Thanks!